# after_destroy callback order in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, callback

I am using PostgreSql as database and Rails 3.1.3 and ruby 1.9.3
I have 3 models.

- `Activity`
- `ActivityObject`
- `ActivityObjectActivity`

They are related this way.

**Activity**

> has_many :activity_object_activities,:dependent => :destroy
>   has_many :activity_objects, :through => :activity_object_activities
>
> after_destroy :do_something_on_activity_object_related

**ActivityObject**

> has_many :activity_object_activities, :dependent => :destroy
>   has_many :activities, :through => :activity_object_activities

**ActivityObjectActivity**

> belongs_to :activity, :dependent => :destroy
>   belongs_to :activity_object

When I do a destroy on an activity, I observe the `activity_object_activities` table entry is getting deleted before the call of `do_something_on_activity_object_related` due to `dependent: destroy`.
So because of this, when the `do_something_on_activity_object_related` method is called when the activity is destroyed, it is not able to find out the `activity_object` associated with the activity.

Is there a method by which I can call this `do_something_on_activity_object_related` before the associations related with the activity are destroyed.
Is there any way I can change the order of the `after_destroy` callbacks.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 7):

You could take responsibly for the delete/destroy dependencies yourself and make sure they get triggered after you have finished your `do_something_on_activity_object_related`

So instead of

```
has_many :activity_object_activities,:dependent => :destroy
has_many :activity_objects, :through => :activity_object_activities

after_destroy :do_something_on_activity_object_related
```

do this:

```
has_many :activity_object_activities
has_many :activity_objects, :through => :activity_object_activities

after_destroy do
    do_something_on_activity_object_related

    ActivityObjectActivity.destroy_all(activity_id: self.id)
end
```

When removing items from the join table you should be fine by using `delete_all` instead of `destroy_all`. But you used destroy in your example to I used it here too.