# Callbacks order in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have code in my model file like this:

```
after_destroy :method_1
after_destroy :method_2
```

Do method_1 and method_2 execute together or method_1 first then method_2?
Does it make a difference if I do:

```
after_destroy :method_1, method_2
```

A reference to the documentation would be great. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [after\_destroy callback order in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984284/after-destroy-callback-order-in-rails)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ActiveRecord::Callbacks](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) documents the order in "Ordering callbacks".

Non-transactional callbacks are executed in the order the are defined.

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :log_children
  after_save :do_something_else

  ...
end
```

When a Topic is saved, log_children will be executed, then do_something_else.

Transactional callbacks (after_commit, after_rollback) are the opposite, the last defined transactional callback is executed first.

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :log_children
  after_commit :do_something_else

  ...
end
```

When a Topic is committed, first do_something_else runs, then log_children.

If there's any doubt, you can combine them into a single callback.

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :commit_callback

  private def commit_callback
    log_children
    do_something_else
  end

  ...
end
```

Answer (score -1):

There's no proper documentation about that, but it is pretty easy to check:

```rb
  after_create :callback_1
  after_create :callback_2

  private

  def callback_1
    puts "CALBACK 1 !!!"
  end

  def callback_2
    puts "CALBACK 2 !!!"
  end
```

will result this output:

```
CALBACK 1 !!!
CALBACK 2 !!!
```

and if you change this to

```rb
  after_create :callback_2
  after_create :callback_1

  private

  def callback_1
    puts "CALBACK 1 !!!"
  end

  def callback_2
    puts "CALBACK 2 !!!"
  end
```

The output will change to:

```
CALBACK 2 !!!
CALBACK 1 !!!
```

The same way works with `after_create :callback_1, :callback_2` and `after_create :callback_2, :callback_1`.

So, the conclusion is:
Callbacks are executed in the order they were registered.

Comment: There's at least one exception: ["_In case there are multiple transactional callbacks, the order is reversed._"](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fb4a3fbf1f1404be39e6d4027cf6b97c080de30a/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb#L215:L262).

Comment: agreed, @Schwern 's described this at his answer.